# What the DeviceIocontrol API function will do?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++

Please explain what does this VC++ code do? Is it possible to convert this code to Delphi2010?

```
void CDMOnLineView::OnActionGetdata()
{
    bool retCode;
    DWORD retByte = 0;
    int TmpHigh, TmpLow;
    UCHAR HIDData[64];
    int LastX, LastY;
    UCHAR Button;
    CDC* pViewDC = GetDC();

    if(yPos > 500) yPos = 0;
    else yPos = yPos + 16;  

    if(hDriver == NULL)
    {
        pViewDC->TextOut(10,yPos,"Driver not connect yet.");
    }
    else
    {
        IO_Param.CallerHandle = m_hWnd;
        IO_Param.Model = DM_A4;
        retCode = DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IOCTL_DM_READ_DATA, &IO_Param, sizeof(DM_PARAM), HIDData, 
                                6, &retByte, NULL);
        if(retCode)
        {
            if(retByte != 0)
            {
                Button = HIDData[1] & 0x01;
                TmpLow = (int)HIDData[2];
                TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[3];
                LastX = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00);
                TmpLow = (int)HIDData[4];
                TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[5];
                LastY = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00);
                sprintf(szStringBuffer, "Button: %d, X: %.5d, Y: %.5d", Button, LastX, LastY);
                pViewDC->TextOut(10,yPos,szStringBuffer, strlen(szStringBuffer));
            }
            else pViewDC->TextOut(10,yPos,"Return bytes incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorCode = GetLastError();
            sprintf(szStringBuffer, "Call IOCTL_DM_READ_DATA fail. Error: %d", ErrorCode);
            pViewDC->TextOut(10,yPos,szStringBuffer, strlen(szStringBuffer));
        }
    }

    ReleaseDC(pViewDC);
}
```

What the `DeviceIocontrol` function will do? Please try to explain the parameters also.

thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the "translation" of all those bitwise operations in the code, hopefully those would get you going:

The operators you need to know about:

- `&` as the bitwise `AND` operator.
- `|` is the bitwise `OR` operator
- `<<` is the  bitwise SHIFT LEFT operator

The translations:

```
Button = HIDData[1] & 0x01; // C
Button := HIDData[1] and $01; // Delphi

TmpLow = (int)HIDData[2]; // C
TmpLow := Integer(HIDData[2]); // Delphi

TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[3]; // C
TmpHigh := Integer(HidData[3]); // Delphi

LastX = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00); // C
LastX := (TmpLow and $00FF) or ((TmpHigh shl 8) and $FF00); // Delphi

TmpLow = (int)HIDData[4]; // C
TmpLow := Integer(HIDData[4]); // Delphi

TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[5]; // C
TmpHigh := Integer(HIDData[5]); // Delphi

LastY = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00); // C
LastY := (TmpLow and $00FF) or ((TmpHigh shl 8) and $FF00); // Delphi

sprintf(szStringBuffer, "Button: %d, X: %.5d, Y: %.5d", Button, LastX, LastY); // C
pViewDC->TextOut(10,yPos,szStringBuffer, strlen(szStringBuffer)); // C

Caption := Format('Button: %d, x: %.5d, y: %.5d', [Button, LastX, LastY]); // Delphi
```

Comment: Thanks Cosmin, I already did this in delphi, the actual problem is, the value for LastX and LastY are in Hexa Decimal before formatting to string. That values we can see while debugging the code. That's why I'm telling it is in Hex values. I don't know they are using any kind conversion factor using to pixel size depends on the machine DPI.

Comment: It's not hexadecimal, what the Delphi debugger is showing you is irrelevant: It needs to show you the data somehow, and it needs to be text. I have no idea why it's showing you integers in Hex, but those Integers are just like any other Integers. Just use them.

Comment: If you don't know the scaling of those values, do an experiment: Take a note of what (X,Y) you get for the top-left of the device, do the same for the bottom-right; When you know the bounds of the values, you can scale them any way you want.

Comment: Ok, I debugged in VC++, i will try to find the scaling factor. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

DeviceIoControl calls custom driver function. Driver is kernel-mode program representing some computer device. Drivers have standard operations (like open, close, read, write, which are called using CreateFile, CloseHandle, ReadFile and WriteFile API) and custom driver-specific operations, called using DeviceIoControl. Details about these operations are described in the driver documentation.

Every custom operation has generic interface: operation code, input and output buffers, which may contain any information.

Answer (score -1):

The `DeviceIoControl` function is [documented at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28VS.85%29.aspx).  User mode programs use it to interact with device drivers.

Converting this code is pretty simple. The call to `DeviceIoControl` maps across trivially. The only area that you are likely to struggle with is the C bitwise operations. If you don't have a copy of [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) to hand, then you should!

Comment: Well, it looks like it might read 6 bytes of data. But really, how could you expect anyone to know what it does? We have no idea where it comes from. Why don't you ask whoever wrote it what it does? Presumably the device driver that it talks to has documentation that describes how this call is to be interpreted.

Comment: This data reading from a HID Device. To get the X and Y position of pen Ink data. The Device driver vendors not interested to disclose the technique, so i'm trying to find out it. That's why I'm seeking help. I'm not expert in driver programming.

Comment: It's really impossible for anyone other than the device vendors to know for sure what how their driver works. If they don't document it, then you'll have to reverse engineer it. We can't do that because we haven't got one of these things. Where did this code come from? Also, why are you cross-posting this?

Comment: One final suggestion. Why attempt to translate this code in order to attempt to reverse engineer the device? You'll likely make mistakes when doing the translation which will render your reverse engineering impossible. Why don't you use the C++ code to do the probing of the device?

Comment: accepting, but I'm familiar with Delphi.So, the other modules also written in Delphi.

Comment: @Able I understand that and when you get as far as production code then you'll want to do it in Delphi. Read what I said again, I did not advise you against writing final code in Delphi. If you have code that runs and successfully talks to the device then extract as much value as you can from that code. Where did that code come from by the way?

Comment: That code given by the Vendor's support team as a demo for On-Line writing function. What the On-line function doing is when we click on the On-line button the Digital Notepad orientation will change from Landscape to Vertical. But they doesn't provide the code for that functionality. But they provide the Demo apps in C++, the output of that apps is X and Y axis values. Now I'm trying to use that values and showing the writing things in my apps window using GDI API's.